# Remove the SearchIcon as hint in the searchView

Tags: android, android-image, searchview

I am doing an application where for example when i click on the image(it is a searchView)

[image]

the search pad opens !

and it looks like
[image]

but here the default search icon (magnifier) gets displayed but this dissappears as soon as some text is entered

[image]

but i dont want that magnifier to be displayed even the image is clicked for the first time

and here i am not using any xml file

my code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(this);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        relative.setLayoutParams(params);
        setContentView(relative);

        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this);
        traverseView(searchView, 0);
//      searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        LayoutParams searchViewparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//      searchViewparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        searchView.setLayoutParams(searchViewparams);
        relative.addView(searchView);
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void traverseView(View view, int index) {
        if (view instanceof SearchView) {
            SearchView v = (SearchView) view;
            for(int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
                traverseView(v.getChildAt(i), i);
            }
        } else if (view instanceof LinearLayout) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
            for(int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
                traverseView(ll.getChildAt(i), i);
            }
        } else if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) view).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            ((EditText) view).setHintTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (view instanceof ImageView) {
            ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Log.v("View Scout", "Undefined view type here...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code and xml file.

Comment: posted the code @SiddharthVyas

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've had trouble with this too. I combined the tutorial I found and an existing answer found here in stackoverflow.

```
int magId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
ImageView magImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(magId);
magImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Take note that searchView is a LinearLayout, so use LinearLayout.LayoutParams to avoid an exception.

I also tried this but it doesn't remove the view. I can't seem to figure why.:

```
magImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

For the other views that you need to change, refer [to this tutorial.](http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/)

Comment: I am getting NPE on `magImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));` which means `magImage` is null, although I can't figure out why :-(

Comment: but in v7.SearchWidget we cannot hide searchhint icon by this method. Just do one thing where you get the instance of SearchView just check that you are not write  
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
method

Comment: For app compat [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633952/how-to-delete-or-change-the-searchview-icon-inside-the-searchview-actionbar/33229228#33229228)

Comment: Not writing `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);` in addition to `setVisibility(View.GONE);` did the trick for me too. Weird behavior though.

Comment: I used the android.support.v7.appcompat.SearchView.
To solve hide it I Used:
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
searchIcon.setImageDrawable(null);

Answer (score 73):

In my app i've used `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` and to hide search icon this worked for me :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    ...
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:searchIcon="@null"
/>
```

Comment: This works for me.  The elongated discussion makes me worry about how compatible this solution is with different hardware, but it's by far the cleanest.

Comment: Programatically is also possible: searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

Answer (score 32):

I've simply put *@null* to `searchHintIcon` attribute:

```
<style name="SearchViewMy" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

and applied that style in my app theme

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewMy</item>
</style>
```

Works for me.

Comment: Simple and straightfoward.

Answer (score 27):

Try these three lines:

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
android:searchIcon="@null"
android:searchHintIcon="@null"
```

*It works only for android.widget.SearchView

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR: Simply setting the `EditText`'s hint to the empty string is enough to remove the hint icon.**

I found an answer that actually works. There's a lot of stuff on changing the icon using reflection - such as discussed at [Styling the ActionBar SearchView](http://novoda.com/blog/styling-actionbar-searchview). This website *IS* a great resource, but unfortunately the search hint `ImageView` does not change (even though the reflection does not cause errors). The only way that I was able to remove this image was this:

```
try {
    int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
    searchPlate.setHint("");
}
catch (Throwable t)
{
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should place this in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, and get a reference to your `XML`-declared `SearchView` using something like:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
```

Answer (score 4):

I just met the same problem, here are some reference links.

http://blog.luxteam.net/2013/11/04/styling-appcompat-searchview/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/android-support-lib-19.1.0/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java

The key is in the following function, it sets the icon as an `ImageSpan`.

```
private CharSequence getDecoratedHint(CharSequence hintText) {
    // If the field is always expanded, then don't add the search icon to the hint
    if (!mIconifiedByDefault) return hintText;

    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   "); // for the icon
    ssb.append(hintText);
    Drawable searchIcon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(getSearchIconId());
    int textSize = (int) (mQueryTextView.getTextSize() * 1.25);
    searchIcon.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);
    ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(searchIcon), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return ssb;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution is **searchHintIcon** attribute

```
<style name="SearchViewStyleMyApp" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
        <item name="queryBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <!-- note that this is how you style your hint icon -->
        <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
        <!-- The hint text that appears when the user has not typed anything -->
        <item name="queryHint">@string/search_hint</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 4):

For androidx you can do like this

```
ImageView magImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
magImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
magImage.setImageDrawable(null);
```

It's work for me

Answer (score 2):

Use "searchHintIcon" attribute in your styles for that:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

You can replace @null with any drawable res you want

Answer (score 2):

It's answer

```
ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);

ViewGroup linearLayoutSearchView =(ViewGroup) searchViewIcon.getParent();
linearLayoutSearchView.removeView(searchViewIcon);
```

Comment: in older android, when you set the searchIcon to null it still pushes the search text over quite a bit, as if the icon was still there taking up space.   This answer works to remove that empty space

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the *searchHintIcon* property as null in your Searchview.

> <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
> **app:searchHintIcon="@null"** />

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(this);
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            relative.setLayoutParams(params);
            setContentView(relative);

            SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this);
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            traverseView(searchView, 0);
    //      searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            LayoutParams searchViewparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //      searchViewparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            searchView.setLayoutParams(searchViewparams);
            relative.addView(searchView);
        }
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void traverseView(View view, int index) {
            if (view instanceof SearchView) {
                SearchView v = (SearchView) view;
                for(int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    traverseView(v.getChildAt(i), i);
                }
            } else if (view instanceof LinearLayout) {
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
                for(int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    traverseView(ll.getChildAt(i), i);
                }
            } else if (view instanceof EditText) {
                ((EditText) view).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                ((EditText) view).setHintTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
            } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else if (view instanceof ImageView) {
                ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                Log.v("View Scout", "Undefined view type here...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry buddy i am not getting you the above is the whole code which i wrote and please just post a comment with the code adding the above lines please

Comment: yaar just Seticonifiedbydefault karee toh bhi yehi procedure aa jayega but i just want to remove that magnifier i mean i should not get that hint at any cost

Comment: yes, Seticonifiedbydefault remove that default icon which you need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42312/discussion-between-hummer-and-harshit-rathi)

Answer (score 0):

with v7 Widget , if you use searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false) the beahvior of the search view differs . You only set hint icon to @null in xml. Also you can apply this manner for other icons.

Answer (score 0):

## androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

If you use androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView:

You can hide the icon using this:

```
val magImage = searchView.findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon) as ImageView
magImage.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it`s ugly, but it only works for me:

```
MenuItem menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
mSearchView = (SearchView) menuSearch.getActionView();

SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = mSearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete");
SpannableStringBuilder stopHint = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
stopHint.append(getString(R.string.search_hint));
Method setHintMethod = clazz.getMethod("setHint", CharSequence.class);
setHintMethod.invoke(searchAutoComplete, stopHint);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question, but this helped me a lot in my case: If you are trying to hide inside a menu, none of the questions posted here worked for me. What solved the problem was:
Instead of putting

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

inside the item in menu, you can change for:

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
```

And, inside this layout, you can add this piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:searchHintIcon="@drawable/nothing_drawed"/>
```

And, finally, inside the drawable you just create it with nothing inside, example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</selector>
```

Only this method worked for me. When I tried to hide the searchHintIcon, setting to @null or anything else, it remained the same thing as if I had written no code.