# Remove searchIcon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-search

I want to remove the search icon in the hint-field of the searchView (see image attached).

[image]

I've tried multiple solutions, in particular this:

```
int magId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
ImageView magImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(magId);
magImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Taken from this: [Remove the SearchIcon as hint in the searchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323990/remove-the-searchicon-as-hint-in-the-searchview) but without any success. Ideas? :)

Comment: Instead of changing the layout params on the image view, have you tried setting a new drawable on the imageview - maybe with a color drawable with the same background color of the actionbar or just a transparent color?

Comment: yes, I've tried both setting the visibility to gone and changing the image's source.. but without any result :(