# Remove magnifier icon in searchfield

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I change or remove the magnifier icon of the EditText input in an android SearchView?

[image: Magnifier icon of android edittext search view]

SOLUTION ====

Its an ImageSpan which is set only in the hint text.

Simply do:

```
int id = resources.getIdentifier("search_src_text", "id", "android");
View autoComplete = searchView.findViewById(id);
autoComplete.setHint(R.string.what_you_like) // or a custom span
```

Comment: I think this will help you solve the problem. 

[Click !][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323990/remove-the-searchicon-as-hint-in-the-searchview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it this way in my application (to change the icon, but you can probably adapt it to hide it). If someone has an easier way, I'll be glad to hear it (like in XML for example).

```
    try {
        Resources resources = this.getResources();
        int id = resources.getIdentifier("search_src_text", "id", "android");
        View autoComplete = searchView.findViewById(id);
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete");
        Method textSizeMethod = clazz.getMethod("getTextSize");
        Float rawTextSize = (Float) textSizeMethod.invoke(autoComplete);
        int textSize = (int) (rawTextSize * 1.25);

        Drawable searchIcon = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
        searchIcon.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);

        SpannableStringBuilder stopHint = new SpannableStringBuilder("   ");
        stopHint.append(this.getString(R.string.search_quotes));
        stopHint.setSpan(new ImageSpan(searchIcon), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        Method setHintMethod = clazz.getMethod("setHint", CharSequence.class);
        setHintMethod.invoke(autoComplete, stopHint);
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTace();
    }
```

From [How to style the ActionBar SearchView programmatically](http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/).

Comment: You should give credits to the original developer: http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/

Comment: I could not find the original link... Thanks for providing it