# Why is Android's SearchView widget's ImageView (with id=search_mag_icon) returning null?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, searchview, android-search

The default `SearchView` has a search icon in the search hint when it is expanded. I want to remove this icon from the hint.

[image]

So I saw [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323990/remove-the-searchicon-as-hint-in-the-searchview#answer-22320059). It gives the following solution in `onCreate()`:

```
int magId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
ImageView magImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(magId);
magImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Looking at the [**xml code of Android's `search_view.xml` here**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml), this solution does make complete sense, **but I am getting a `NullPointerException` at te 6th line in the following snippet:**

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchActivity_searchView);
        int magId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "magId > "+ magId);
        ImageView magImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(magId);
        Log.i(TAG, "magImage > "+ magImage);
        magImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

and before the exception, it prints:

```
08-07 14:13:15.740: I/SearchActivity(2548): magId > 16909188
08-07 14:13:15.740: I/SearchActivity(2548): magImage > null
```

**So what should I do about this?**

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchview.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
ssb.append(hintText);
searchEditText.setHint(ssb);
```