# Remove the space of the search icon in the SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I'd like to get rid of the search icon in `SearchView`

[image: Search icon in <code>SearchView</code>]

I've tried:

- `setIconified(false);`
- Adding `<item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>` to the SearchView style.

And none of these worked, any clue?

Comment: share your `code`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323990/remove-the-searchicon-as-hint-in-the-searchview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa follow this link

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see your code in order to help but adding these to your XML will help if you are using android.widget.SearchView in a recent API level (i.e. 21 or higher):

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
android:searchIcon="@null"
android:searchHintIcon="@null"
```